# Disable the default function when tap a while on the Ipad safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

Default keeping tap on the screen (eg. hold tap for 1 second) will **show a option of save image / copy**. However , I would like to turn off that function for my web app , is it possible? I have tried to replace the event of touchmove to selectall , however it does not work . Thanks for helping.

```
addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, true);
```

Comment: Are you certain you're listening to the right event (`'touchmove'`)?
If I want to save a image on my iPad, I can't move my finger (much), or the popup won't show.

Comment: For sure the touchmove is not the correct event, therefore I wonder which is the correct event name .

Comment: Have a look at the different [event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Touch_events#Setting_up_the_event_handlers) for touch events.
(I'm not sure you can even prevent the "save?" dialog)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought it would be worth mentioning that you can do this with pure CSS. It's probably not a really great idea, because neither IE10 or Opera Mobile support it. But it can be done, and in the future, this would probably be a better way than with JavaScript. Or if you're only talking about iPhones and iPads, this method would work really well. Here's an example [on CodePen](http://codepen.io/howlermiller/pen/axmCu).

The code is simple:

```
.notouch {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Just give the class of `notouch` to any image that you want to effect.

If you want to do it to every image on the page, do this:

```
img {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

And I should give an obligatory speech on useability. By doing this you're overriding default functionality that people expect to be there all the time. It makes for a really bad experience for you to turn off something like this, unless you have a really, *really* good reason to do so. So please, make sure you do.

**Edit**:

To get rid of the magnifying glass, use this code:

```
.notouch {
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
}
```

With `-webkit-user-select` set to 'none' you may not even need to turn off pointer events, but I'm not sure about that. I updated the CodePen as well.

Comment: Thanks, if the pointer events is disable, an mangifer is shown , is there any way to disable it as well?

Comment: I think I found a way. Updating answer.

Answer (score 4):

It could be beneficial to disable not only preventDefault, but other properties as well:

```
e.preventDefault(); 
e.cancelBubble = true;
e.returnValue = false;
return false;
```

Also the event, are you sure it's touchmove ?

Comment: `stopPropagation` is IE-only, OP's asking for iPad functionality.